# How does AngularJS display images?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm using Http-server and AnglarJS. below is the folder structure.

[image: screenshot of folder structure]

In `search.html` I want to display `abc.png`.

I used an `img` tag and did what I usually do with HTML:

```
<img  src="../img/abc.png"  >
```

Now I received an error:

> `GET http://localhost:8000/img/abc.png 404 (Not Found)`

So I declared `img` tag like this:

```
<img  src="/website/img/abc.png"  />
```

And it works well. It surprised me.

So how does AngularJS display images?

Comment: try this <img src="IMG/abc.png"/>

Comment: angular has nothing to do with displaying images ... you just didn't get the path to your image right.

Answer (score 2):

This has *nothing* to do with AngularJS specifically.

The `../` bit is a *relative* path. You can reverse engineer what the base path was by looking in the network tab of your browser, and see what full path it resolved to (which gives a 404).

The `/website` bit in your second example is *not* a relative path. It'll try to find the file starting from the root of your application. The same advice as above (look at the network tab) holds for reverse engineering what it did.

To use the first form with relative paths, you might need multiple `../../../` combined with going into subfolders again. Impossible to tell for us what the path should be specifically, that's particular to your environment.